# How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?

Tags: git

I accidently commited the wrong files to Git,but didnt push the commit to the server yet.How do i undo those commits from the git.

I tried to add a question in Git but it didnt work .

Answer (score 1):

Easiest thing is to just go back to as if you hadn't committed anything:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~
```

Then you can get everything out of the index:

```
git reset .
```

And it's like you hadn't done anything.